# How to get column value with insert query using sequel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel, mysql2, ruby-grape

How to fetch column value at the time of inserting into MySQL DB using sequel. Tried below query getting type error: *no implicit conversion to integer*.

```
DB[:table].import([:x, :y], [[1, 2]], [:return=>:primary_key]).
```

Comment: Try without the square brackets? Like `1, 2]], :return => :primary_key)`

Comment: Above one working.

Comment: Great! I have added as an answer

Answer (score 2):

As per [the docs](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-import), you should be passing opts in without the square brackets, like so:

```
DB[:table].import([:x, :y], [[1, 2]], :return =>: primary_key)
```